# What is the difference between linear and non-linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

In machine learning, I understand that Linear regression assumes that parameters or weights in equation should be linear. For Example:

> Y =  W1*X1+W2*X2

is a linear equation where X1, X2 are feature variables and W1, W2 are parameters.

also,

> Y = W1*(X1)^2 + W2*(X2)^2

is also linear as parameters (W1, W2) are linear with respect to Y.

Now, I read some articles stating that in the equation like

> Y = Log(W1)*x1 + Log(W2)*x2

can also be made linear by considering other variables V1 and V2 as:

> V1 = Log(W1)
>   V2 = Log(W2)

thus,

> Y = V1*X1 + V2*X2

So, in this sense, any non-linear equation can be made linear then what is non-linear regression here. I think I am missing something important here. 
 I am a beginner in the field of Machine Learning. Can somebody help me?

PS - This is my first question here at StackOverflow so if there is an error in writing an effective question, please forgive me.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's not really a programming question as presented.  You might try asking it on one of the other Stack Exchange Network sites (like mathematics or AI).

Comment: In short, though, as long as the `X`s have an exponent of 1, and the coefficients are constants, it doesn't matter if the constants are expressed as functions (of any kind) of other constants. If `W1` is constant with respect to `X`, so is `log(W1)`.

Comment: The replacement of `log(W1)` with `V1` just makes it "look" more linear; it doesn't change the fact that it was already linear.

Comment: @chepner, if it is already linear then what is non-linear?

Comment: `Y = W1*(X1)^2 + W2*(X2)^2` is non-linear, because neither `X` has an exponent of 1. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination.

Comment: @chepner is mistaken. Please refer to my answer. Linear regression only refers to linearity in the parameters. The comment would be correct if it were referring to raising the $W_1$ and $W_2$ weights (parameters) to exponents other than 1: $Y=W_1^2X_1^2 + W_2^2X_2^2$ Is a nonlinear regression. However, the posted $Y=W_1X_1^2+W_2X_2^2$ is a linear regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In statistics, a linear regression refers to linearity in the parameter. For instance, $y=a + bx +cx^2$ is a linear regression, since we only add and subtract multiples of the weights $a$, $b$, and $c$ (the multiples being the data: $x$). However, $y=a +log(bx)+cx^2$ involves a nonlinear log transformation of the $b$, making that a nonlinear regression.

Comment: I was thinking the same but we can separate log(bx) as log(b) + log(x) so it can be considered as linear again: y = a+log(b)+log(x)+cx^2, where a+log(b) can be considered as biased term. So how do we decide if the equation is linear or not?

Comment: @ka1shi clever thinking, but that would still be nonlinear. A property of a linear transformation $T$ is that $T(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$. What is $0+log(0)+log(x)+0x^2$? That is undefined, so it isn’t zero. The way to determine if a regression is linear is the usual way for linear transformations: $T(a\vec{x}+b\vec{y})= aT(\vec{x})+bT(\vec{y})$. Trying $\vec{\beta}=\vec{0}$ to check if that results in $0$ also can be a quick way to rule out a regression as nonlinear, though that test alone cannot confirm a regression as linear.